# Echo out from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [lastModified] => 1465097340000
            [name] => Ulminia
            [realm] => Zangarmarsh
            [battlegroup] => Rampage
            [class] => 3
            [race] => 4
            [gender] => 1
            [level] => 100
            [achievementPoints] => 14915
            [thumbnail] => hellscream/74/113337162-avatar.jpg
            [calcClass] => Y
            [faction] => 0
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [averageItemLevel] => 710
                    [averageItemLevelEquipped] => 709
                    [head] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 125899
                            [name] => Warmongering Gladiator's Helm
                            [icon] => inv_helm_mail_raidhunter_p_01
                            [quality] => 4
                            [itemLevel] => 710
                            [tooltipParams] => Array
                                (
                                    [transmogItem] => 71356
                                    [timewalkerLevel] => 100
                                )
```

I want to echo out from the [head] array the [id] and the [quality]. If i just echo out the [id] everything works, but if i want to echo out the [quality] too, it doesn´t work.

My code:

```
$items = $r['result']['items'];
echo 'Head: '.$items['head']['id']['quality']."\n";
foreach($items['head']['tooltipParams'] as $key => $value){
    echo 'head_'.$key.': '.$value.'\n';

}
```

Comment: do you need to echo all the values???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$items['head']['id']['quality']."\n";` is trying to read the element with the key `quality` **inside** the array stored inside `id`. However, `id` is not an array, which is why this fails.

In order to read two fields, you need to read them seperately:

```
echo 'Head: ID=' . $items['head']['id'] . ', quality = ' . $items['head']['quality'] . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $items['head']['id']['quality'];
```

The above statement means you are printing out the subkey "quality" of key "id", which doesn't exist.

You need to concatenate both key values as follows:

```
echo $items['head']['id'] . ' ' . $items['head']['quality'];
```

... or

```
echo $items['head']['id'], ' ', $items['head']['quality'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `id` and the `quality` are in the same array.

```
//ID
echo $items['head']['id'];
//Quality
echo $items['head']['quality'];
```